# Why I can't prevent that the user edit a PrimeNG form field value?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am working on an Angular project using **PrimeNG** and I am finding the following difficulties trying to disable the editing of a text form into a field.

Basically into the HTML code of my component I have something like this:

```
<input id="disabled-input"
       type="text"
       pInputText
       [disabled]="disabled"
       formControlName="UID" />
```

As you can see it is using the **formControlName** attribute to retrieve data from a *FormGroup** object defined into the TypeScript code (it works fine). As you can see I also set this in order to avoid the possibility to edit this field value:

```
[disabled]="disabled"
```

Then into the TypeScript code of this component I declared this variable:

```
disabled = true;
```

So I expected that the input field editing was disabled but it is not, infact I am obtaining this:

[image]

The strange thing is that doing in this way in another component it is working. The only difference is that in this other component the fileds are not bound to a form but the field value is bound useing the **[(ngModel)]**, in this way:

```
    <input id="disabled-input"
           type="text"
           pInputText
           [disabled]="disabled"
           [(ngModel)]="orderDetail.UID" />
```

In this second case it works fine and it is impossible for the user edit the field value.

Why in the first case I can't prevent that the user edit the field value? I can I obtain this behavior?

Comment: Try to set disabled in your component, instead of putting as html attribute, `[disabled]` attribute is not allowed in reactive form (at least you will get warning). `this.myGroup.get('UID').disable();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case doesn't work because it is a mix of the template driven and reactive forms. From the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#choosing-an-approach):

> Template-driven forms rely on directives in the template to create and
> manipulate the underlying object model. They are useful for adding a
> simple form to an app, such as an email list signup form. They're easy
> to add to an app, but they don't scale as well as reactive forms. If
> you have very basic form requirements and logic that can be managed
> solely in the template, template-driven forms could be a good fit.

IMO avoid template forms for the production software. They are not scalable and testable enough.

For Reactive forms one need to disable the form control.

```
this.formGroup.get('UID').disable();
```

Answer (score 3):

Though it may not be for what you are looking, instead of

[disabled]="disabled"

I used

readonly="readonly"

to achieve this. The field isn't disabled but it can't be changed, which was my goal.

```
      <input readonly="readonly" pInputText class="p-inputtext-sm" formControlName="featureName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to disable it.

```
 [readonly]="view ? 'readonly' : null"
```

this will disable input feilds